# Printing an heap memorised as an array level by level in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, printing, heap

I wanted to implement heapsort, and watch all the steps of how it works graphically,so I want to print a heap level by level. It ended up being much harder than actually understanding heapsort. Still, it would be cool to have a function to do that. How do I do it?

```
function printheap(a){
  let i = 0;
  let c = 0;
  let t = "\t";
  let s = " ";
  while(Math.floor(a.length/(2**i)>1)){
    t += "\t"
    i++
  }
  i = 0;
  while(Math.floor(a.length/(2**i)>1)){
    t = t.slice(0, -1)
    s += " "
    process.stdout.write(t + a[c])
    c++
    for(let j = 0; j<(2**i)-1&&c<a.length; j++){
      process.stdout.write(s + a[c])
      c++
    }
    console.log("\n")
    i++
  }
}
```

I tried doing it with this code, but it works funny, and pretty randomly, and I don't even know what I'm doing, and it's even pretty inefficient can anyone make a prettier solution?

for example given the array [3, 8, 7, 15, 17, 30, 35, 2, 4, 5, 9]
I would expect something like:

```
              3

        8          35

   15     17     30    7

 2   4  5   9
```

Comment: Could you provide sample input (for `a`) and the expected output for it?

Comment: It's not actually a sorted heap, but you get the idea, I've added an example

Comment: It is nice that you added an example, but it would be great if you would react to the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to perform an inorder traversal and consider that each next value in that order takes up its own column in the output. So you get those columns from left-to-right and the width of each column is determined by its corresponding value only. What varies is the depth, i.e. the line in which the value should appear.

You could create a function for producing the inorder traversal (maybe a generator), and let it yield both the value and its depth in the tree. From that information you can build up the output string:

```js
function* inorder(a, i=0, depth=0) {
    if (i >= a.length) return;
    yield* inorder(a, i*2+1, depth+1);
    yield [a[i], depth];
    yield* inorder(a, i*2+2, depth+1);
}

function toString(a) {
    return Array.from({length: 32 - Math.clz32(a.length)}, (_, level) =>
        Array.from(inorder(a), ([val, depth], i) =>
            depth === level ? val : " ".repeat((val+"").length)
        ).join(" ")
    ).join("\n");
}

const a = [2, 5, 7, 6, 10, 9, 8, 15, 11, 18, 12, 21];

console.log(toString(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

A binary heap is represented in the array in breadth-first order. That is, given your heap, `[3, 8, 7, 15, 17, 30, 35, 2, 4, 5, 9]` (which, by the way, is not a valid binary heap but I'll assume that it's in some state of being manipulated, so we'll go with it), the first element is the root. The next two elements are the root's children, the next four elements are the children's children, etc. Conceptually, the array looks like this:

```
3
8,7
15,17,30,35
2,4,5,9
```

You'll notice that at each level there are twice as many nodes as on the previous level.

The trick to printing the tree structure is that you have to know how wide your widest line is. That is, the maximum number of nodes you'll have to display on the bottom line. If you know how many nodes are on the bottom line, then you know how wide your line has to be, you know what the center position has to be, and therefore you can center your levels on that position.

Fortunately, it's easy to figure out how wide that bottom line has to be.

The number of leaf nodes in any heap is `(n+1)/2`, where `n` is the number of nodes in the heap. But that tells you how many leaf nodes there are, not how many nodes are at the bottom level. That is, given this heap:

```
            1
         3     7
        4 x   x x
```

There are indeed `(n+1)/2 = 3` leaf nodes. But the bottom level, if it were full, would contain 4 nodes. The "missing" nodes are represented by the x's in that figure.

The number of levels in a heap with `n` items is log<sub>2</sub>(n)+1. Given a heap with 4 items, log<sub>2</sub>(n) is equal to 2. Add 1 and you get 3, which matches the heap shown above.

The number of nodes that *can be* at the lowest level of a heap with `n` levels is 2<sup>(l-1)</sup>, where `l` is the number of levels.

Your example heap has 11 nodes. log<sub>2</sub>(11) is 3 and change. Add one and truncate the result, you get 4. There are four levels to your heap. That means that there can be up to 2<sup>(4-1)</sup> = 8 nodes at the bottom level of your heap.

If you know how wide your widest element is (i.e. if it's numbers, you know that the largest number is 3 digits, or 2 digits, whatever), then you can easily figure out how many character positions (assuming a fixed-width font) the bottom level will require: simply multiply the number of potential bottom-level nodes by the maximum width (be sure to add space between the numbers), and you have your answer.

So, to print the heap, you do the following:

1. Compute how many levels are in your heap (`h = log2(n)+1`)
2. Compute how many nodes can be at that bottom level (`m = 2^(h-1)`)
3. Compute the width of the bottom level, if it were full (`w = m*(elementWidth + spacing)`)

Now, you begin iterating over the array, sequentially, starting at the first element. There is one node at the top level. So you print that centered at horizontal position `w/2`. There are two nodes at the next level. You center the line containing those two at `w/2`. Four nodes at the next, etc.

There's one tricky part that I've left for you to play with: spacing the elements on the line at each level. I've not done it in a while, but as I recall it's just a bit of fiddly arithmetic that you'll figure out in a few minutes once you get everything else working.

Here's the basic loop for the sequential scan of the array:

```
h = log2(n)+1  // height of tree
m = 2^(h-1)    // number of nodes at bottom level
bottomLineWidth = m*(elementWidth+spacing) // you'll have to supply the constants
centerPos = bottomLineWidth/2
levelNodes = 1
index = 0
for lvl = 1 to h
{
    for (j = 0; j < levelNodes && index < n; j++)
    {
        nSpaces = ?? // compute space between nodes at this level
        line = line + a[index].ToString() + nSpaces
        index = index + 1
    }
    leftPadding = ?? // compute left padding to center line at centerPos
    print line
    levelNodes = levelNodes * 2;
}
```